# Are there any requirements in Kashrut about how livestock must be treated/reared during its life before reaching the slaughterhouse?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Obviously there are requirements that it must be actually slaughtered by a qualified slaughterer, using a sufficiently smooth and sharp knife, and the animal must then have been sufficiently healthy so as to pass the “glatt” kosher inspections for pulmonary “adhesions”.

But are there any specific requirements about how the animal must have been treated during the course of its lifetime, apart from these minimum requirements of pulmonary health?