# Not to slaughter an animal in the presence of another

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I remember learning that you should not shecht an animal in a way, that another live animal will see it.

Is there a source to this?

Related: [Are there any requirements in Kashrut about how livestock must be treated/reared during its life before reaching the slaughterhouse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138053/are-there-any-requirements-in-kashrut-about-how-livestock-must-be-treated-reared)

Comment: This might be some sort of derivation from לא תשחט האם על הבנים

Comment: @Loani I do not think so it was something to do with the health and the pain of the animal that looks

Answer (score 3):

I also thought it was an explicit law but, after looking into it, it is less direct than that. I found a Pitchei Tshuva that brings down what you remember

It all starts with a gemara in [Chulin 55b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.55b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> The mishna states: Or if its lung shriveled [ḥaruta] by the hand of
> Heaven, the animal is kosher. The Sages taught in a baraita: Which is
> a ḥaruta? It is any animal whose lung shriveled. If this occurred by
> the hand of Heaven, e.g., if the lung shriveled from fright of thunder
> and lightning, the animal is kosher. **But if it happened by the hands
> of a person who frightened it, e.g., if it witnessed another animal
> being slaughtered, it is a tereifa.**

The SA in [YD 36:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.36.14?lang=bi) brings this as halacha

> צמקה כולה אם מחמת בני אדם שהפחידוה כגון ששחטו אחרת לפניה וכיוצא בזה
> טריפה

on which the [Pitchei Tshuva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Hirsch_Eisenstadt) [comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.36.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> עיין בתשובת בית אפרים חיו"ד סי' כ"ו שכתב שלא נכון מה שהרבה בני אדם
> באים אל השוחט ואוחזים עופות בידיהם ועומדים סביב בכדי שמיד שיגמור שחיטת
> עופות של זה יתחיל בשלו ובפרט בערב יו"כ בשחיטת הכפרות ואין זה נכון כי
> יש בזה משום צער ב"ח וגם יש חשש צימוק הריאה ואף שאין להחמיר להצריך
> בדיקה מ"מ לכתחלה יש ליזהר בין בעופות בין בבהמות.

He writes (in the name of the [Beit Efraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_Zalman_Margolioth)) that it is not right when people line up with chickens in their hands and surround the *shochet* to have him slaughter one after the other, especially during *kaparot* of Yom Kippur, as it is "tsar balei chaim" and there is also a suspicion of shriveled lungs. **He writes that *lchatchila* one should refrain from having chicken and larger animals witness the *shechita* of other animals.**

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you may be thinking of [Hilchot Sh’chitah 8:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Ritual_Slaughter.8.9), where Rambam rules that if an animal becomes physically frightened because it sees another animal being slaughtered, it (the frightened one) is treif.

Comment: To clarify, the Rambam is not saying that any animal that is frightened by seeing another animal slaughtered becomes treif. He is saying that an animal that has shriveled lungs as a result of fear בידי אדם (e.g. seeing someone shecht another animal) is a treifa.

Comment: @malkizedek That’s what I meant by “physically”. Apologies if unclear.